# Why doesn't dataframe set string column to non-factor despite setting the option, stringsAsFactors = F?

Tags: r

HI I like to generate a frequency table with string as a non factor, however I find this error.

```
> str ( data.frame  (  table ( iris$Species) , stringsAsFactors = F ) )
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Var1: Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 2 3
 $ Freq: int  50 50 50
```

the only way that I can do this now is save the dataframe, temp for example and set the Var1 column `as.character()`

In addition, setting `options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)` also does not remove factors.

thanks!

Comment: Try `str ( as.data.frame  (  table ( iris$Species) , stringsAsFactors = F ) )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `as.data.frame` instead to get the desired behavior (as already mentioned).  But this does not answer your question why `data.frame` fails.

The reason is not obvious and I had to look inside the source code of `data.frame` to find it.  The reason is that `table` returns a single *named* numeric vector.  I.e. the "Var1" column is inferred from the names of a numeric vector, not from a character vector.

The following lines in `data.frame` then come into play

```
 xi <- if (is.character(x[[i]]) || is.list(x[[i]])) 
      as.data.frame(x[[i]], optional = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors)
    else as.data.frame(x[[i]], optional = TRUE)
```

Here we see that `as.data.frame` gets called *without* invoking `stringsAsFactors = F`, because it has detected a numeric vector.

---

**Addendum:**

An additional question arose in the comments.  Namely that "using `as.data.frame` without explicitly setting `stringAsfactors = F` still fails despite setting `options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`"

The reason for this is separate, and could arguably be described as a bug in the R source code.  Here is the function definition header for `as.data.frame.table` which is the method that gets dispatched for a table object:

```
function (x, row.names = NULL, ..., responseName = "Freq", 
          stringsAsFactors = TRUE, 
          sep = "", base = list(LETTERS))
```

Notice that `stringsAsFactors = TRUE` is taken as the default value - the value set in options never gets checked.  Compare this to other `as.data.frame` methods  which typically defer to the value set in options as their default. For example, `as.data.frame.list` is defined like this:

```
function (x, row.names = NULL, optional = FALSE, ..., cut.names = FALSE, 
  col.names = names(x), fix.empty.names = TRUE, 
  stringsAsFactors = default.stringsAsFactors())
```

Comment: thanks - that is interesting. So what you are saying is that data.frame fails because it the Var1 was  returned as a named numeric vector however is this why even using as.data.frame without explicitly setting `stringAsfactors =F` still fails despite setting `options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`

Comment: @Ahdee - that is a separate question.  I explained it too now in the answer

Comment: thanks for the in depth breakdown.  This was great since it has taught me an interesting way to look and debug.  I wonder if ver 4 which now has factor set to F by default would have this issue as well.